# Hibernate: My folder structure is correct but when running app it still cant locate hibernate.config.xml file on resources folder

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, netbeans

I am working with Maven, on Netbeans, on Windows

I have my full configured **hibernate.cfg.xml** file on
"/src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml"

I have ***triple checked this is a fact***.
[This is my folder  structure on Netbeans (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzM0f.jpg)

When running I get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: 
Could not locate cfg.xml resource [/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml]
```

This is my hibernate cfg.xml file:

```
<!-- This file should be referenced in the configure() method!!! -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC

"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <! -- url -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@toshiba-pc:1521:SYSTEM</property>
    
    <! -- username -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">system</property>
    
    <!-- password -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">27111995</property>
    
    <!-- database driver -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>

  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And on my main class the relevant lines are these:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
     cfg.configure("/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");
 ...more code...
```

So basically I have been trying to get around this with no success at all. Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it!
My solution was to create a new File object using the System.property("user.dir") method and pass it to the Configuration constructor:

```
String roothFolder = System.getProperty("user.dir");
File hibernateConfigFile = new File
(roothFolder + "/src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.configure(hibernateConfigFile);
```